# How is it possible that PolyLog[2, 1.1] returns an imaginary number?

Tags: special-functions, complex

Given that `PolyLog` is defined as `PolyLog[n_, z_] == Sum[z^k/k^n, {k, 1, ∞}]`,

```
Sum[1.1^k/k^2, {k, 1, 100}] -> 22.0448
Sum[1.1^k/k^2, {k, 1, 1000}] -> 2.77305*10^36
Sum[1.1^k/k^2, {k, 1, 10000}] -> 9.31353886174236*10^406
Sum[1.1^k/k^2, {k, 1, 100000}] -> 2.041716249550151*10^4130
```

and `Limit[1.1^k/k^2, k -> ∞] -> ∞`, how is it possible that `PolyLog[2, 1.1] -> 1.962 - 0.299426 I`?

It is not wrong, and it is all over the Internet that the polylogarithm has a branch cut discontinuity at $\Re z \ge 1$, but I don't understand how it is computed.

Comment: The infinite sum for the dilogarithm is only defined for $|z|\le 1$; otherwise, you use [analytic continuation](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog2/17/01/01/0002/). A similar situation exists for $\zeta(s)$: the defining sum works only for a certain domain, which interestingly is not part of the region the associated hypothesis deals with.

Answer (score 8):

People dealing with special functions for the first time ask questions like this a lot; I suppose it's time to write something on this topic.

Let's go back to a much simpler case of the [polylogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html):

$$\mathrm{Li}_1(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k}=-\log(1-x)$$

Following your train of thought, $\mathrm{Li}_1\left(\frac{11}{10}\right)$ should also be nonexistent, since $\frac{\left(\frac{11}{10}\right)^k}{k}$ blows up as $k\to\infty$. But, we know that $-\log\left(1-\frac{11}{10}\right)=\log10-\pi i$, which is ***complex***! What gives?

The right way to look at it is that the defining series for $\mathrm{Li}_k(x)$ is actually only valid on a *finite* domain, dictated by its **radius of convergence**. Geometrically put, the series is only valid within a certain *disk* in the complex plane. For the polylogarithm in particular, the series only converges for $|x|<1$, and values on the unit *circle* may or may not give a convergent series. (Going back to the logarithm example, consider both the cases of $x=1$ and $x=-1$.)

So how is this complex value you got obtained? In general, one often works with special functions whose defining expressions are only limited to a certain domain, but either have *a*. alternative expressions that work for a wider domain, not necessarily including the original; or *b*. satisfy functional equations that allow one to relate values within and outside the original domain. This is the concept of **analytic continuation**.

With $\mathrm{Li}_1(x)$, you are quite likely aware of other definitions for the logarithm, which then allow you to compute it for values outside the usual domain $|x|<1$. For the dilogarithm, there is this [reflection formula due to Euler](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog2/17/01/01/0002/):

$$\mathrm{Li}_2(x)+\mathrm{Li}_2(1-x)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\log(1-x)\log x$$

I'll leave it to you as an exercise on how to use it to compute the value you observed.

Comment: If memory serves, the **radius of convergence** of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$  $$R=\lim_{x\to \infty}\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|$$

Comment: @Shutao, yes, and you can use that to show that the series for the polylogarithm is only valid within the unit disk.

Comment: An even simpler example is the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k=1/(1-x)$.
How is it possible that for $x=2$, where all terms are strictly positive, the resulting formula ends up giving $-1$ instead of infinity? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation